# RxJS: switchMap inside merge doesn't work to make a conditional observable return

Tags: angular, rxjs6

Inside a merge I want the first observable to be conditional between two different ones, but it seems adding a switchMap inside a merge doesn't work.

I don't understand why the `switchMap` inside the `merge` never triggers and only handle pure observables.

```
switchMap(() => {
       return merge(
          switchMap(() => {
            if (condition) {
              return of(something);
            }
            return of(somethingelse);
          }),
         obs2$
        );
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge takes Observables as it's arguments, but SwitchMap is not a function that creates an Observable. SwitchMap is a pipeable operator that goes inside a pipe().

One way of solving this problem would be:

```
switchMap(() => {
  let myVar;
  if (condition) {
    myVar = something;
  } else {
    myVar = somethingelse;
  }
  return merge(
    of(myVar), 
    obs2$
  );
})
```